# code for finding longest substring without repeating characters not working

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, sliding-window

I have written the following code for finding the length of the longest substring without repeating characters below, but it doesn't work - would anyone know why? (I know there are other solutions on the internet that work but the following code is written in my style and I'd ideally like to adapt it)

```
def longestSubstring(str):

    start = 0
    maxLen = 1

    hashSet = set()

    for i in range(len(str)):

        if str[i] not in hashSet:
            hashSet.add(str[i])
            maxLen = max(maxLen, i - start + 1)
            continue

        else:

            while str[start] != str[i]:
                hashSet.discard(str[start])
                start += 1

            hashSet.discard(str[start])
            start += 1

    return maxLen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just one line, remove the 2nd `hashSet.discard(str[start])` you don't want to remove this character from the set, you just need to increase start, it is the character you just encountered.